# Bad Storing of Strings in emu8086

Tags: string, assembly

In emu8086 4.08 I'm using this syntax to declare my *Code Segment* and initialize the program:

```
Code SEGMENT
ASSUME CS:Code, DS:Data, SS:Stack

MOV AX, Data
MOV DS, AX
MOV ES, AX
```

And these are the declarations of strings in my *Data Segment*:

`Str1 DB 50,0,50
 Str2 DB 50,0,50`

It suppose that this couple of instrutions declare two Strings with 50 spaces for characters. And I'm using this syntax for reading both strings from the input user:

`LEA  DX, Str1
 MOV  AH, 0Ah
 INT 21h`

Now, if I put `Hello World` in both, the emulator stores in this way:

[Store the second string in positions of the first string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cENTw.png)

Why does this happen? Is it because I am do something wrong in the syntax of the strings? Is it necessary to put `MOV ES, AX` in the program?

Comment: You declare strings like this : `Str1 DB 50 DUP(0)`. A string with 50 chars. In your code you declared a string with three bytes : 50, 0 and 50.

Comment: My teacher teach me wrong. Thanks. So, what the happen if I put Str1 50,0,50 DUP(0)  ?

Comment: With DUP(0) you say that Str1 will storage fifty zero's and when you read some data, it'll overwrite zeros to readed data.